# Printing WPF Document

Tags: c#, wpf

How to specify the number of copies to be printed before you open the print dialog?

I need to print shipping labels and need to print copies equal to number of boxes.

Currently this is being achieved using the print dialog box but would be nice to achieve this in the code itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried anything in code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very important that you read the **FAQ** and post your question.You need to write the code and then ask for any assistance.

The code here is in C# (Have not been tested)

```
  PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();//System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings
  PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();

  settings.Copies = Copiesnumber; //put your number of copies

  printDoc.PrinterSettings = settings;

  PageSettings MyPage = new PageSettings(settings);

  printDoc.DefaultPageSettings = MyPage;
```

Comment: My bad, that was my first question ever. Will keep that in mind.

Thanks for your help.